# Read a specific file type with a single thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, file

I have a folder which has multiple files, I intend to read those files and insert into their type speificed tables.

Problem:

I am reading the files with mutliple threads, but everytime a thread tries to read a type (string) of a file that is being read by another thread, it crashes with the error:

> Transaction (Process ID 69) was deadlocked on lock | communication
>   buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the
>   deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DoExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand
>   command)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand
>   command)

I could do it with a single thread but that takes alot of time, with multi-threading, How could I possible avoid the crash?

Code:

```
 public int InsertData(string data, string tableName)
        {
            string query;
            var token = JToken.Parse(data)["data"];
            JArray jArrayData;
            if (token is JArray)
            {
                jArrayData = token as JArray;// JArray.Parse(data) as JArray;
                foreach (var item in jArrayData.Children())
                {
                    var itemProperties = item.Children<JProperty>();
                    query = ServerHelper.CreateInsertQuery(itemProperties, tableName);
                    ExecuteQuery(query);
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }

   private int ExecuteQuery(string query)
        {
            if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }


 public static string CreateInsertQuery(JEnumerable<JProperty> itemProperties, string tableName)
        {
            string[] nameArray = itemProperties.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
            string[] valuesArray = itemProperties.Select(x => "'" + x.Value.ToString().Replace("'","''") + "'").ToArray();
            //check for null
              string query = "Insert Into " + tableName + " (" + string.Join(",", nameArray) + @")"
         + " values(" + string.Join(",", valuesArray) + ")";
        return query;
        }
```

The code that tries to execute queries in parallel is :

```
   public void PerformInitialization()
        {
            ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            ct = ts.Token;

            ChangeProcToDat();

            string strMaxThreads = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxThreads"].ToString();
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strMaxThreads))
            {
                bool parseSuccess = Int32.TryParse(strMaxThreads, out maxThreads);
                if(parseSuccess == false)
                {
                    maxThreads = 1;
                }
            }

            processQueueTasks = new Task[maxThreads];

            processData = new ProcessData();

            for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
            {
                processQueueTasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessQueue(), ct);
            }
        }

 public void ProcessQueue()
    {
        bool cancelled = false;
        try
        {

            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {

                    Directory.CreateDirectory(queueFolderPath);

                    DirectoryInfo queueFolderDi = new DirectoryInfo(queueFolderPath);

                    FileInfo datFile = queueFolderDi.GetFiles("*.dat", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
                    while (datFile != null)
                    {
                        string processingFileName = datFile.FullName.Replace(".dat", ".proc");
                        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(processingFileName);
                        File.Move(datFile.FullName, processingFileName);

                        try
                        {                                

                            if (file.Name.Contains("_ABC_"))
                            {
                                var fileNameArr = file.Name.Split('_', '.');

                                var fileType = "";  # this is the type of the file
                                if (fileNameArr.Length >= 3)
                                {
                                    fileType = fileNameArr[3];
                                }

                                // the db part

                               var content = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);

                                int responseCode = 0;
                                InsertData(content, reportType);

                                File.Delete(file.FullName);


                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Log.WriteToFailed("Error processing queue file " + file.Name + " "
                                + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace + Environment.NewLine);

                        }


                        datFile = queueFolderDi.GetFiles("*.dat", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime).ToList().FirstOrDefault();


                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.WriteToFailed("Error processing files in the queue folder."
                                + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace + Environment.NewLine);

                }
                finally
                {
                    cancelled = ct.WaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.WriteToFailed("Error occured in send thread. Message:" + ex.Message + "\n Stack trace:" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any threads?

Comment: @John The treading part is independent it calls the method, let me add that as well.

Comment: This is a SQL Server error and yet, there's no database access code in the question. A deadlock in the database has nothing to do with threads, it has to do with different connections trying to use resources locked by the other. It happens, although it typically means that some connection or transaction was kept open for too long

Comment: This is clearly a SQL problem, but the question doesn't show any database related code. Without that... not sure what you want us to comment on here?

Comment: @John Added the thread part as well.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Exactly! like I stated I did try it with a single connection and it works fine but is too SLOW! Let me add the db part as well.

Comment: @AlexJim the error is about a *database*, not files. *Remove* the unnecessary code and add only the data access parts. Threading doesn't matter. Deadlocks occur if even two connections use a bad query

Comment: Note that if you spawn multiple threads running this method, you'll likely get the same list of files to work from. Panagiotis is right about the cause, though.

Comment: @Niklas7 locking in a *single* client doesn't prevent deadlocks. Fixing the query can take care of that

Comment: yes, running complex SQL updates in parallel can make it easy to get deadlocked, depending on your work pattern and isolation level. However... often, database access to a single resource won't parallelize well *anyway* - I'd be tempted to process them async+sequential

Comment: @AlexJim `but is too SLOW!` probably means a bad query. Multithreading doesn't fix query performance issues, it *compounds* them due to increased locking and can even lead to .... deadlocks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is slow because a file could be very long compared to others so it takes time reading it before it shifts to the next one.

Comment: @AlexJim why would that affect the performance of the database query? Unless you keep the connection open while processing all files, thus accumulating locks? You still haven't posted any relevant code.

Comment: @AlexJim question: you seem to have multiple threads doing `ProcessQueue`, but I don't see how they aren't all doing *all* the work (there is no per-worker state that shards the work up between them)... so ... aren't they all going to be touching *roughly* the same things at the same time?

Comment: A moment guys, im adding the db code. and if I create the connection for each thread (which I am) the deadlock occurs since the threads try to insert data of the same file type to the same table!

Comment: @AlexJim How does more threads speed up reading a file? If you have a Database involved you are almost certainly latency bound. Please stop trying to use Threads.

Comment: @Aron more threads means reading different files at the same time and inserting to their tables faster?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added the missing db functions as well.

Comment: @MarcGravell Indeed, that is whats intended. to read the all the files by threads and insert their data into the table of by their file type!

Comment: @AlexJim the only relevant code seems to be a method that creates a query. `ExecuteQuery` is missing. Do you use a global transaction? Global connection? Do you execute each INSERT in a separate connection? The rest of the code isn't relevant.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `ExecuteQuery` is right there inside the `InsertData` method. Yes I use a different connection for each thread. i.e. each `INSERT` in a separate connection.

Comment: @AlexJim as for performance, *DON'T* execute a single INSERT for each row. The fastest way is to use SqlBulkCopy and send a batch of rows to the server directly.

Comment: @AlexJim I suggest *removing* all the irrelevant code or moving it to a section *after* the relevant parts. This has nothing to do with threading, in fact, there are several duplicates that ask how to improve INSERT performance

Comment: @AlexJim and no, the code for `ExecuteQuery` is missing. We still don't know how you execute the queries. The only hint is the use `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data`, a library that became obsolete over a decade ago as the DbFactory functionality became part of ADO.NET 2.0 itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos SqlBulkCopy would definitely improve the performance but I doubt if it'd solve the deadlock error!

Comment: @AlexJim as for why INSERTs can cause deadlocks, if the table has no primary key or index, the server may have to take an exclusive lock on an entire data page or the table itself. If you keep the connection open for long, those locks accumulate and you may get two connections trying to lock pages locked by the other

Comment: @AlexJim yes it would, because it would completely eliminate the need for threads. It's the *threads* that cause the deadlocks - and harm performance too. You're writing to the *same* disks, over the *same* network. Using multiple threads wont' multiply the network cards or disks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I truly appreciate your efforts in making this crystal. I added the `ExecuteQuery` method as well.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so you're saying I should not even be using threads? How could I read `n` files and store their content in their tables altogether then? :/

Comment: @AlexJim for starters don't use a global thread the way you do in `ExecuteQuery`. That's exactly what caused lock accumulation. Entlib *DOESN'T* work that way, it opens and closes connections only when needed. There's a reason all samples contain a `using` block for the connection. Opening a new connection costs nothing thanks to thread pooling

Comment: @AlexJim `ExecuteQuery` should change to `using(var conn=new SqlConnection(connectionString){....}` or `using(var conn=myDbFactory.CreateConnection(...)){...}` at least.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos cool, I could change that in the `ExecuteQuery` will add a `using` clause and perhaps remove the `ConnectionState` state check too? but do you think that's the main culprit?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Chnaged it to something like: `private int ExecuteQuery(string query)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PredatarConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: @AlexJim Thread is an abstraction for a slice of CPU time. How does more of that make "reading data from a disk" or "sending data to a database" fast? Use C# threads IF AND ONLY IF you need more CPU. You can get massive performance improvements simply by switching to a TPL Dataflow style single threaded concurrency. Switching to `DbConntextion.ExecuteQueryAsync` can let you batch up and execute, sidestepping the latency bound issue. Don't use Threads, you aren't a Java developer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the *actual* question is how to quickly insert records from lots of JSON files into a SQL Server table.

**Performance and deadlocks**

The attempted solution is slow because it tries to insert the records Row By Agonizing Row (RBAR). That's the slowest way to do this.

It deadlocks because it uses long lived connections, which means row and table locks are accumulated and held as long as the connection remains open. If the table has no primary key or non-clustered index, SQL Server may have to take more locks at the data page or even table level and keep them as long as the connection stays open.

Using threading in this case can make things worse as multiple connections wait for each other. If the missing indexes cause excessive locking, the connections may end up locking data pages required by each other and hence, deadlock.

There are *many* ways to insert JSON data into SQL Server

**JSON in SQL Server 2016 and later**.

SQL Server 2016 and have JSON functions that can be used to parse JSON strings. One could write a stored procedure that takes a JSON string as a parameter, parses it with OPENJSON and inserts the values into a table. Stealing the example from [OPENJSON – The easiest way to import JSON text into table](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/09/22/openjson-the-easiest-way-to-import-json-text-into-table/) :

```
 INSERT INTO Person
 SELECT * 
 FROM OPENJSON(@json)
 WITH (id int,
       firstName nvarchar(50), lastName nvarchar(50), 
       isAlive bit, age int,
       dateOfBirth datetime2, spouse nvarchar(50))
```

Sending the entire contents of the file to SQL Server won't use *more* data than sending the individual text values.

**OPENROWSET**

Another option is to load JSON files directly with [OPENROWSET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/10/07/bulk-importing-json-files-into-sql-server/) and parse it with OPENJSON eg :

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable(ID,Name,Price,Pages,Author)
SELECT book.id, book.name, book.price, book.pages_i, book.author
 FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\JSON\Books\books.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
 WITH( id nvarchar(100), name nvarchar(100), price float,
 pages_i int, author nvarchar(100)) AS book
```

**Client-side parsing and SqlBulkCopy**

Another option is to parse the text on the client side, eg with JSON.NET and bulk-insert the data using SqlBulkCopy. SqlBulkCopy uses the same mechanisms used by `BULK INSERT` or `bcp` to insert data as fast as possible with minimal logging.

[FastMember's](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) ObjectReader can be used to convert the list of items to the IDataReader expected by SqlBulkCopy. The code could be something like this :

```
var json=File.ReadAllText(path);
var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SomeType>>(json);
using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) 
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data, "Id", "Name", "Description")) 
{ 
  bcp.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable"; 
  bcp.WriteToServer(reader); 
}
```

Or, as a method :

```
void ImportJson<T>(string path,string tableName,string[] fields)
{
    var json=File.ReadAllText(path);
    var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
    using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) 
    using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data, fields)) 
    { 
        bcp.DestinationTableName = tableName; 
        bcp.WriteToServer(reader); 
    }
}
```

**Client-side parsing and multi-row INSERTs**

Instead of executing individual INSERT statements, performance can be improved by batching them or using multi-row INSERT statements, eg :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE TableA (Col1,Col2)
VALUES
(Val11,Val12),
(Val21,Val22)
```

Writing this by hand is boring though. One can use another one of Marc Gravell's creations, [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) to perform multiple INSERTS:

```
var json=File.ReadAllText(path);
var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
conn.Execute("INSERT INTO TableA (Col1,Col2) VALUES(@Prop1,@Prop2)",data);
```

There are other options too. The data can be sent as a table-valued parameter, another thing that's [easier to do with Dapper](https://medium.com/dapper-net/sql-server-specific-features-2773d894a6ae)

Comment: I really love the `SqlBulkCopy` approach but I have triggers on tables that delete a row if it exists in the table already, hence I used the Insertion in a loop inside the `CreateInsertQuery` method. However, I am changing the triggers and will give this one a shot. Will come back to give an update on this.